# Symfony collection does not save reference ID and cannot remove element

Tags: symfony, doctrine, sylius

I've  added an attachments to Product with relationships Attachment - Product ManyToOne. Schema is created correctly, problem is, when I save product, product_id is not set in attachments table, what I solved by using DataTransformer where I am adding product reference manually. Another problem is that I cannot remove attachment from CollectionType.

ProductAttachment class:

```
  <?php

     namespace AppBundle\Entity;

     /**
     * ProductAttachment
     */
    class ProductAttachment
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $filename;

    private $filepath;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $filetype;

    private $product;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFilepath() {
        return $this->filepath;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $filepath
     */
    public function setFilepath($filepath) {
        $this->filepath = $filepath;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getProduct() {
        return $this->product;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $product
     */
    public function setProduct($product) {
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    /**
     * Set filename
     *
     * @param string $filename
     *
     * @return ProductAttachment
     */
    public function setFilename($filename)
    {
        $this->filename = $filename;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get filename
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFilename()
    {
        return $this->filename;
    }

    /**
     * Set filetype
     *
     * @param string $filetype
     *
     * @return ProductAttachment
     */
    public function setFiletype($filetype)
    {
        $this->filetype = $filetype;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get filetype
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFiletype()
    {
        return $this->filetype;
    }
  }
```

Here is Product class:

```
    <?php


namespace AppBundle\Entity;


use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Product as BaseProduct;
use Sylius\Component\Product\Model\ProductTranslation;
use Sylius\Component\Resource\Model\TranslatableTrait;

class Product extends BaseProduct {

  private $nid;
  private $attachments;


  use TranslatableTrait {
    __construct as private initializeTranslationsCollection;
  }

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->initializeTranslationsCollection();
    $this->attachments = new ArrayCollection();
  }


  /**
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function getAttachments() {
    return $this->attachments;
  }

  /**
   * @param mixed $attachments
   */
  public function setAttachments($attachments) {
    $this->attachments = $attachments;
  }


  public function addAtachment(ProductAttachment $attachment) {
    if($attachment != null) {
      $this->attachments->add($attachment);
    }
  }

  public function removeAttachment(ProductAttachment $attachment) {
    $this->attachments->remove($attachment);
  }
  /**
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function getNid() {
    return $this->nid;
  }

  /**
   * @param mixed $nid
   */
  public function setNid($nid) {
    $this->nid = $nid;
  }

  public function createTranslation() {
    return new ProductTranslation();
  }


}
```

Doctrine definitions:

Product:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Product:
    type: entity
    table: sylius_product
    fields:
        nid:
            type: integer
            nullable: true
    oneToMany:
        attachments:
          targetEntity: ProductAttachment
          mappedBy: product
          cascade: ["persist","remove"]
          orphanRemoval: true
```

ProductAttachment:

```
AppBundle\Entity\ProductAttachment:
    type: entity
    table: sylius_product_attachment
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\ProductAttachmentRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        filename:
            type: string
            length: 255
        filetype:
            type: string
            length: 255
        filepath:
            type: string
            length: 255
    manyToOne:
        product:
          targetEntity: product
          joinTable:
            name: sylius_product
            joinColumns:
              product_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
              attachment_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Answer (score 1):

According Symfony [Collection Of Form](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) documentation you should saving the "Inverse" side

```
  public function addAtachment(ProductAttachment $attachment)
  {
      $attachment->setProduct($this);
      $this->attachments->add($attachment);
  }
```

There is also no need to check if $attachment is null (you are casting your variable to Class type)

Comment: Thanks. I should read documentation first. I had no idea how "adders" and "removers" work and that they are triggered after form is saved.